# When I publish c# app the command line args are NOT passed through

Tags: c#, publish

I have an app that works in debug. The command line args are passed into the application.

But when I publish from VS to a directory on disk, and then launch the application with

> MyApp.application "MyArg"

Then the arguments do not appear to be passed to the app.

```
static class Program
{
    public static string[] Args;
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Args = args;
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to show more code than this.

Comment: Are you sure? have you done a trace (like print the contents of args to a text-file?)

Comment: Yes in Form1 I show arg in a MessageBox, but as there isn't one I get an index issue.

Answer (score 0):

You must define the main class and output type in the project properties.
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKu7y.png)

Comment: It is a problem with ClickOnce security - this get "ticked" every time I Publish!